# Unable to connect to the remote server” using restclient, this works on local machine but not on Azure app service

Tags: c#, azure, cloud, rest-client

This code works locally using restclient .net library but same code produces "unable to connect to remote when deployed on Azur app service"

```
    var client = new RestClient {BaseUrl = new Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["WalletUrl"])};
    var hgh = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["GetWalletRequest"];
    var requests = new RestRequest(Method.POST){
        RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json
     };
    requests.AddHeader("content-type","application/json");
    requests.AddParameter("application/json", req, ParameterType.RequestBody);
    requests.AddBody(req);
    var response = client.Execute(requests);
```

Comment: Just to eliminate the obvious, are you sure that the remote service you are connecting to doesn't have any firewall/gateway or IP-based access control that is restricting use?  Like you local IP is whitelisted, but Azure is not?

Comment: No, I don't think so. I do make successful connection to the endpoint from my local machine without any problem. The problem only occurs when I tried to use the same code on azure app service dev tier.

Comment: Also, is the remote service  you are connecting publicly available ? Are you able access the same service endpoint from outside your domain/org network ?

Comment: Thanks everyone, the problem was resolve by just shutting down current app service and  creating a new one with the same parameter. I guess it was a problem from the infrastructure side. Many thanks to everyone

Comment: could you post it as an answer to make it easily visible for others?